# deleting entire row with jquery json ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

What I want to achieve is to delete an entire row. First I display the table, then if you click on "delete" button from every row then a confirmation modal shows up asking you if you want to delete that row.

I'm trying to work with jquery, ajax, json and PHP. I'm still learning of course.

So far what I have is this:

**Javascript file:**

```
function callToModal(data){
 $('#myModal3 .modal-body p').html("Desea eliminar al usuario " + '<b>' + data + '</b>' + ' ?');
 $('#myModal3').modal('show');
 $('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var id = $(this).data('id');
 $('#myModal3').data('id', id).modal('show');
});


$('#btnYes').click(function() {
// handle deletion here
var id = $('#myModal3').data('id');
alert(id);
$.ajax({
    url: "deleteFrontUser",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id:id
          },
      success: function(html){
        //alert(html);
        $('[data-id='+id+']').parents('tr').remove();
        $('#myModal3').modal('hide');
      }      
    });
   return false;
});
};
```

**In my admin.php file:**

```
public function deleteFrontUser(){
    // var_dump($_POST['id']);die();
    $rowId = $_POST['rowId'];

    $result = array();

    $front = UserDs::getInstance()->getUserById($id);
    UserDs::getInstance()->deleteItem($front);

    $result["message"] = "Usuario eliminado";

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

The view (please notice that I'm using Smarty template engine):

```
<div class="portlet-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-users">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Avatar</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone">Usuario</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone">Email</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone">Provincia</th>
                    <th class="hidden-phone">Miembro desde</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {foreach $frontusers as $frontuser}
                <tr>
                    {if $frontuser->frontavatar_id eq null}
                    <td><img src="{site_url()}assets/img/avatar.png" alt="" /></td>
                    {else}
                    <td><img src="{site_url()}assets/img/avatar1.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    {/if}
                    <td class="hidden-phone">{$frontuser->username}</td>
                    <td>{$frontuser->name}</td>
                    <td>{$frontuser->lastname}</td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone">{$frontuser->email}</td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone">{$frontuser->state}</td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone">{$frontuser->creation_date|date_format:"%Y/%m/%d"}</td>

                    {if $frontuser->status eq 2}
                    <td ><span class="label label-success">Activo</span></td>
                    {else}
                    <td ><span class="label label-warning">No Activo</span></td>
                    {/if}

                    <td><a class="btn mini blue-stripe" href="{site_url()}admin/editFront/{$frontuser->id}">Modificar</a></td>

                    <td><a href="#" class="btn mini red-stripe confirm-delete" role="button" onclick="callToModal('{$frontuser->username}');" data-id="{$frontuser->id}">Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>



                <!-- modal -->
                <div id="myModal3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Eliminar</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
                        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn red" id="btnYes">Confirmar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end modal -->

                {foreachelse}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><span class="text-error"><i class="icon-exclamation"></i> No hay Usuarios cargados.</span></td>
                    </tr>
                {/foreach}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The modal displays when you click on delete button of an specific row, but here's the funny thing: the first time you press delete, it doesn't erase the row. When you press that or any other row (after pressing once delete) the row is deleted. So that is one problem, and the other problem is that I can't manage to send data to my php file so I can erase it from the database.

How can i solve this?

I have a customized fiddle with this, if you want to check out: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/wLg3K/)

Comment: When you press delete, have you checked to see if it actually deletes the row from the database and its just not being reflected by the html yet?

Comment: @echochamber it only reflects in the browser, not in my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is this:

See my previous post in order to have the correct js file and view: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123557/send-parameter-to-a-modal-and-then-deleting-row/20272944#20272944)

Php code for deleting entire row from the database would be:

```
public function deleteFrontUser(){

    $rowId = $_POST['id'];

    $result = array();

    $front = UserDs::getInstance()->getUserById($rowId);
    UserDs::getInstance()->deleteItem($front);

    $result["message"] = "Usuario eliminado";

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`url` has to be a valid site located within your website, you can't have a function name within `url`, since the AJAX call won't know in which file the function is located.

So your `url` must be:

```
url: "admin.php"
```

You can, however, add another parameter into your `AJAX`call to tell `admin.php` which function it should execute, something like this would work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        id:id,
        func:"deleteFrontUser"
    },
    success: function(html)
    {
        //alert(html);
        $('[data-id='+id+']').parents('tr').remove();
        $('#myModal3').modal('hide');
    }      
});
```

So on `admin.php` you must receive the posted data BEFORE you enter the function, and you can parse the func variable to tell which function to execute:

```
$rowId = $_POST['id'];
$func = $_POST['func'];

switch ($func)
{
    case 'deleteFrontUser':
        deleteFrontUser($rowId);
    break;
    default:
        // function not found.
    break;
}
```

Wherea `deleteFrontUser` looks something like this:

```
public function deleteFrontUser($rowId)
{
    $result = array();
    // Rest of the code.
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Maybe you need to modify this a bit but this should give you the idea.

For more information take a look at the [$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**Note:**

For best practice's cause, use [php's isset](https://www.php.net/isset) function to determine whether the data was actually posted or not. The [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) operator makes this very easy and short:

```
$emptyString = "";
$rowId = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : $emptyString;
$func = isset($_POST['func']) ? $_POST['func'] : $emptyString;
```

I also recommend using jQuery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, and let it take the parameter "click" and the function of which will be triggered on the click event. `.click` is in general bad practice because it's unable to detect changes within the DOM tree so when you update it with new HTML you're screwed, `.on` allows you to add new elements to the dom tree but still being able to listen to events corresponding to them.

Comment: very impressive how well you explained it. Only that my code works with url: 'nameOfTheFunction'. There's no need to put admin.php, if i do that, then automatically have many errors because of how the path is conformed. What you said later about best practices, i will of course keep that in mind :) thanks

Comment: Maybe it works in some framework. But an up-vote wouldn't hurt if it provided some useful information.

Comment: i think it only works at mine because of how the path is configured! of course an upvote, sorry didn't get in here in the entire weekend. :) thx